# Is there a better way for me to cache HTTP requests in Angular?

Tags: angular, rxjs

So I work on a Angular project in which many of the HTTP responses are used on multiple pages, so I wanted to cache the results on the front end so that they can be shared across the different components.

Here is a a "simple" example of my current implementation:

Service.ts

```
serviceData = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

Component.ts

```
    this.service.serviceData.pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe( response => {
      if (!responseData) {
        this.service.makeAPICall().subscribe(res => {
          this.service.serviceData.next(res);
        });
      } else {
        this.bankBranchDetails = bankData;
      }
    });
```

Using this snippet, I can share the same API results across multiple pages, and I can clear the cache by doing

```
this.service.serviceData.next(false)
```

In this simple example, things seemed fine (Still interested to know if there's a better way of doing this though).

The point where it becomes very complicated is when I need to use the result of one subscription as a parameter for 2 cached HTTP calls.
For example, if I have a beneficiaryList and beneficiaryCategoryList which both depend on the currently selected profile, this is what I end up with.

```
    this._paymentSaService.selectedProfile.pipe(switchMap(selectedProfile => {
      this.selectedProfile = selectedProfile;

      //Clear the beneficiaryCategoryList and beneficiaryListData because the profile just changed, meaning we need to fetch the new results
      this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryCategoryList = new BehaviorSubject<BeneficiaryCategoryInterface[] | false>(false);
      this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryListData = new BehaviorSubject<Beneficiary[] | false>(false);

      return zip(this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryCategoryList, this._manageBeneficiary.beneficiaryList);
    }), takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)).subscribe(([categories, beneficiaries]) => {
      if (!categories || !beneficiaries) {
        this._paymentSaService.getBeneficiaryCategories(this.selectedProfile.ProfileId).subscribe(res => {
          this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryCategoryList.next(res);
        });

        this._manageBeneficiary.getBeneficiariesList(this.selectedProfile.ProfileId).subscribe(res => {
          this._manageBeneficiary.beneficiaryList.next(res);
        });
      } else {
       //Both API calls completed, now we can handle the 2 pieces of data.
      }
    });
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this?
This "solution" seems very overkill and confusing.

I would seriously appreciate any advice here to simplify my current way of doing things, because this project is turning out to be a bit of a birds nest.

EDIT:
I have created a stackblitz with a replica of my implementation.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-axpmm3?file=src/app/app.component.html

Oh, another downside of this implementation that I would love to fix, is that you have to clear the cache of both observables if you want to update even just 1 of them, due to me using a zip.
But if I dont use a zip, the implementation would completely break because as soon as 1 API call finishes, it would kick off both calls again.

Comment: In your `this._paymentSaService.selectedProfile.pipe` subscribe block, it seems like you're always going to hit the `if (!categories || !beneficiaries) {}` block, since you're setting `this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryCategoryList` and `this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryListData` to false on each data emission (which seems correct), but I'm not seeing then why you'd have an `else` block in here. The way this is set up, you will always be requesting new data?

I guess I'm not sure how this script is actually relying on any cached data.

Comment: @VidalQuevedo I attached a stackblitz if that helps you to see how it works. I want to do the call again every time the selectedProfile changes. Because the beneficiaryCategoryList and beneficiaryListData depend on the current selectedProfile. The purpose of the caching is that so other components dont make the same calls again, they all read from the same service

Comment: i'm probably over simplifying everything, but it seems like maybe you're over complicating everything?  can you not just "cache" the value in the service.  you can do this by just putting this into any variable as the service is a singleton.. and then have all components reference the value in the service (or subscribe to an observable that the service returns) and you're done.

Comment: @JBoothUA I really hope that it is me who is over complicating things. I'd love for a simpler solution to work.

I would really appreciate it if you could fork my stackblitz and implement what you have in mind. Please note that it is important that I can clear the cache on demand, and this must fire off the call again to get the latest data.
For example, lets say I have a list of TODOs which I fetch from HTTP and cache so that other components can read from that same value, then I can fire off a request to add a new TODO, which will empty the cache and then it must query the API again.

Answer (score 2):

Looking into your code, I went ahead and simplified things a bit. Basically, since your goal is to just update (and emit) the caches for the `beneficiaryList` and the `beneficiaryCategoryList` every time a new profile is selected, I tried to streamline everything by moving all the logic into the `subscribe` block and removing the `switchMap` and `zip` operators.

In addition, I added a `forkJoin` so you can have more control over *when* your requests happen, since in the original post the responses from your http requests were being fired independently, so you'd never be able to have the response from both delivered at the same time, in case you needed them to do something else with all the data at once.

```js
this.service.selectedProfile.pipe(
  takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)
).subscribe((selectedProfile: any) => {
  this.selectedProfile = selectedProfile;

  /* Update beneficiaries and categories lists now 
  that the selectedProfile has changed.*/  
  this.updateBeneficiariesListAndCategories(selectedProfile).subscribe((res) => {
    // Do whatever you need with returned data
  });
});


/**
 * Place parallel requests to update beneficiaries and categoies
 * for a specific profile and update caches
 */
updateBeneficiariesListAndCategories(profile: any): Observable < any > {

  // Clear beneficiaries and categories 
  this.service.beneficiaryCategoryList.next([]);
  this.service.beneficiaryListData.next([]);

  // Create requests
  const getBeneficiaryCategoriesRequest = this.service
    .getBeneficiaryCategories(selectedProfile.ProfileId)
    .pipe(
      catchError(() => of ([]))
    );
  const getBeneficiariesListRequest = this.service
    .getBeneficiariesList(selectedProfile.ProfileId).pipe(
      catchError(() => of ([]))
    );

  /* Use a forkJoin to place both requests in parallel and
  then do something when both calls have completed (the
  catchError() operator on each request should keep the
  forkJoin from failing completely should either of the
  calls fail).*/
  return forkJoin({
    categories: getBeneficiaryCategoriesRequest,
    beneficiaries: getBeneficiariesListRequest
  }).pipe(
    tap((res: any) => {
      // Update caches 
      this.service.beneficiaryCategoryList.next(res.categories);
      this.service.beneficiaryListData.next(res.beneficiaries);
      console.log(res.categories);
      console.log(res.beneficiaries);
    })
  );
}
```

I forked your stackblitz sample and put my edits here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hnj3ys

Comment: Thank you for your willingness to help. Unfortunately with this implementation, the "refresh" functions don't work. The cache isn't only cleared when the profile changes, there's also other times when the cache needs to be cleared. For example after adding a new beneficiary, I want to be able to empty the cache and make the call again, without having to change the selectedProfile again

Comment: Got it. However, originally, clearing the caches seemed to happen every time a profile was selected, which lead to firing the requests to repopulate them again right away:

`this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryCategoryList = new BehaviorSubject<BeneficiaryCategoryInterface[] | false>(false);
this._paymentSaService.beneficiaryListData = new BehaviorSubject<Beneficiary[] | false>(false);`

However, this should not be a problem when a new profile is added in the suggested reimplementation, since there wouldn't be `categories` or `beneficiaries` associated with a new profile. Just a thought.

Comment: Yes, the required behavior is that when changing profile, the cache is cleared and it fires the requests again. But on top of that, I also need a way to manually clear the cache and fire the requests again, without changing the profile.

Comment: Ok, I updated the script above to move the clearing and refreshing of the categories and beneficiaries to a separate method `updateBeneficiariesListAndCategories ()` that you can use independently at your leisure (for example, in update vs add profile events).